# Parsing an Image from HTML file

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, html-parsing

I am parsing some data from an html file.

=>I am able to parse the strings using :-

```
NSArray *elements4  = [xpathParser1 search:@"//p"]; 
TFHppleElement *element4 = [elements4 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pTag = [element4 content];  
m_pPText.text=pTag;
```

Now , I want to parse an Image from the html file. How can I do that ? Where to store the image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store the image to documents directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to this field. Some brief will help me ?How to store it there(in documents directory) ?

Comment: You need to use NSFileManager. Search on google for the code snippet you will find easily. Search using this query "store UIImage into documents directory iphone sdk"